# how to fetch page rank using java

Tags: java, seo, google-ranking

I am developing SEO application in java
and I am facing problem to fetch the google page rank of the domain.
Can any one suggest me how to do that?
I have tried [the Temesoft pagerank API](http://www.temesoft.com/google-pagerank-api.jsp) for that but unsuccessful.

Please help me with this.  Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Google search brings you a lot of results, including [this recent one](https://github.com/tc/google-pagerank)

Comment: It gives me connection time out every time

Comment: use `tbr` instead of ``search` in the url in PageRank.java. It works with the domain `toolbarqueries`